# Pandas Unable to access count column although it shows up in printing head

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas code to calculate count of transactions per hour basis

```
sliced_data3 = sliced_data[['TransactionHour','TransactionAmt']].groupby(['TransactionHour']).agg(['count'])
```

In `sliced_data3.head(24)`, I see the columns correctly. But I can't access the count column correctly. I always get KeyError.

on checking types - I see this -

```
TransactionAmt  count    int64
dtype: object
```

How do I rename the count column?

I just want to calculate the number of Transactions that happen per hour and take it into a different dataframe.

Comment: try doing a `df.columns` and check if the count column has traiing space or such.

Comment: @Sid `MultiIndex([('TransactionAmt', 'count')],)` . I wanted `MultiIndex([('TransactionHour', 'Count(TransactionAmt')],)`

Comment: @MichaelGardner `ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 24.`

Comment: @PrateekNarendra Fixed `sliced_data3.loc[:,sliced_data3.get_level_values(1)=='count']`

Comment: @MichaelGardner `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_level_values'`

Comment: @PrateekNarendra sorry forgot the columns...last try.  `sliced_data3.loc[:,sliced_data3.columns.get_level_values(1)=='count']`